# Why doesn't my JS script load?

Tags: javascript

To finish my website I need to add a JS script which is applied to the header. I installed a plugin called "JavaScript AutoLoader", made a new directory called "jsautoload" in my child theme folder and inserted the script. I also added code in functions.php for it to load the jQuery library. Some time ago I added the script to the JS folder of my parent theme. None of these methods work. Do I need to do something else?
This is my JS script:

```
<script
   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
   integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
   crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){
   $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
   })
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need a plugin. Save the JS inside your child theme's root folder, and then enqueue it in your child theme's `functions.php` file. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259754/how-can-i-include-3rd-party-library-in-wordpress/259863#259863 or examples in the Code Reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ - and note that jQuery is usually included by default, so make sure you're not enqueueing it twice.

Comment: You may also need to wrap everything in a doc ready function, and handle jQuery Migrate which is also on by default - wrap everything in your second script inside `(function($) { $(document).ready(function(){` (your code) `}); })(jQuery);`